# What skill list should I use for a game set in ancient Greece?

Tags: skills, fate-core

I am pondering over a skill list for Fate Core game set in ancient Greece. Set in Athens of the Classical period (We do not want to pinpoint it on a precise year), the main themes are concerned with War happening everywhere, strong leaders emerging, and the clash of philosophy and mythology. The characters will probably be siding with the Gods against the new things. What should our skill list contain?

I would like the skill list to work for for a +4 cap skill pyramid, because I have no good reason to deviate from this default. It should therefore be somewhat be similar to the default one in Fate Core, which has the 18 skills *Athletics*, *Burglary*, *Contacts*, *Crafts*, *Deceive*, *Drive*, *Empathy*, *Fight*, *Investigate*, *Lore*, *Notice*, *Physique*, *Provoke*, *Rapport*, *Resources*, *Shoot*, *Stealth* and *Will*.

Comment: The point of customising a Fate skill list is to make it fit your own game's needs and expectations; it's something you should be working out with your players rather than presenting to them as *fait accompli* or asking strangers to do for you. Feel free to come to the [chat] and ask for help with brainstorming--or one of the many excellent G+ Fate groups--but this isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange's mainsite Q&A format.

Comment: After having discussed some things on http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17620228#17620228, I do know even better that I know nothing about making Fate skill lists.

Comment: We made characters a few days ago. I told players the problem, described the possibilities of skill lists, giving the examples of Skills, Professions, Approaches and Nothing at all, with what I understood as their advantages and disadvantages. The table settled for free-form generic (“Athlete”, “Priest(ess)”, “Philosopher”, “House Wife”, …) Professions, with closely overlapping professions unified and specialised by stunts.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

I suggest to take *Animal Ken*, *Athletics*, *Contacts*, *Crafts*, *Doxa*, *Empathy*, *Episteme*, *Fight*, *Manipulate*, *Notice*, *Perform*, *Physique*, *Resources*, *Sail*, *Shoot*, *Stealth* and *Will*, taking inspiration from existing games set in mythological Greece.

## Steal from similar games

There are a few games out there that have a similar setting, so let's have a look what they list as skills for characters. Assuming the authors there did their research and spent some good time thinking about which skills to include, this should give good pointers towards creating a good skill list for this Fate game.

*Disclaimer: I have played neither Fate Core nor any of these games, so please feel free to consider this a bad answer.*

### Arete

[Arete](http://games.dungeonmastering.com/arete/) is a game by Nicholas DiPetrillo. It is set in Greek mythology, trying to recreate Hero stories of Greek mythology. Its skill list contains the following 21 skills, corresponding roughly to the Fate Core skills listed:

- Archery (*Shoot*)
- Allure (*Rapport*)
- Wealth (*Resources*)
- Armed Combat (*Fight*)
- Authority (also *Rapport*?)
- Defense (*Athletics*)
- Craft (*Crafts*)
- Might (*Physique*)
- Deception (*Deceive*)
- Sailing (*Drive*)
- Entertain (*Rapport*, again)
- Sneaking (*Stealth*)
- Nature (*Lore*)
- Swiftness (also *Athletics*)
- Oratory (a fourth implementation of *Rapport*)
- Toughness (a second aspect of *Physique*)
- Perception (*Notice*)
- Wrestling (either *Fight* or *Athletics*)
- Religion (also *Lore*)
- Resolve (*Will*)
- Underworld Magic (third *Lore* ability)

Absent are the Fate Core skills *Burglary*, *Contacts*, *Empathy*, *Investigate* and *Provoke*. Instead, *Rapport*, *Lore* and the skills used for fighting are split into multiple implementations.

### Spartan

[Spartan](http://www.topsecretgames.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Spartan.pdf) is a two page rpg designed by McEachern for a two-page tabletop RPG competition, in which players take on the role mythical ancient Greece. It lists 12 skills:

- Crafts: Building, repairing, sabotaging mechanical objects. (*Crafts*)
- Curses: Inflicting misfortune, particularly having to do with vermin (snakes, rats, insects) or the weather. (*Lore*?)
- Diplomacy: Bartering, soliciting aid, building rapport. (*Resources*, *Rapport*)
- Hunting: Ranged attacks, tracking, animal handling. (*Shoot*, *Notice*)
- Illusions: Masking real things with false images. (*Deceive*, *Lore* if magic?)
- Influence: Buying things, knowing people. (*Resources*, *Circles*)
- Lore: Knowledge of history, languages, geography, etc. (*Lore*)
- Performance: Playing music, dancing, acting, lying. (*Rapport*, *Deceive*)
- Physique: Running, wrestling, kicking down doors. (*Physique* and *Athletics*)
- Prophecy: Talking to animals or the dead, who may sometimes offer cryptic hints about the future. (*Lore*)
- Subterfuge: Stealth, attacking unsuspecting targets. (*Stealth*, *Fight*, maybe *Burglary*)
- Warfare: Melee attacks and tactical maneuvers. (*Fight*, mostly)

Absent from this list are again *Burglary*, *Empathy*, *Investigate* and *Provoke*. This game has multiple ways to express *Rapport* and *Lore*, as well.

### Agon

[Aγων](http://www.agon-rpg.com/) is a competitive role playing game, again about mythical Heroes of ancient Greece. Its skill list sports the following 16 abilities:

- Insight: awareness, reason, and wisdom. (*Lore*, *Notice*)
- Grace: agility and poise (*Athletics*)
- Might: physical power, both strength and vigor (*Physique*)
- Spirit: power of the will (*Will*)
- Heal: used to remove wounds (*Lore* or *Physique*)
- Lore: information through careful study, observation, or obscure knowledge (*Lore*, *Investigate*)
- Music: playing of instruments as well as recitation
  of poems and tales. Music may also be used to soothe beasts. (*Lore*, *Rapport*)
- Orate: speak to others and have an effect on
  them, positive or negative (*Rapport*, *Provoke*)
- Athletics: running, jumping, swimming, and climbing (*Athletics*)
- Cunning: stealth, subterfuge, deceit, camouflage, or trickery—and also for resisting those things (*Stealth*, *Notice*, *Deceive*, *Empathy*, maybe *Burglary*)
- Hunt: track, set and detect snares, tame beasts, and
  other woodscraft (a variety of skills)
- Wrestle: grapple, throw, and pin an opponent (*Athletics*, *Fight*)
- Aim (*Shoot*)
- Shield (*Fight*)
- Spear (*Fight*)
- Sword (*Fight*)

Agon really splits down Fight, and still has multiple versions of *Lore* and *Rapport*.

## Skill list for a Fate Core game

Given the observations of those games set in a more mythical Greece, I suggest the following changes.

- Drop *Burglary*, its trappings go to *Stealth*.
- Drop *Investigate*, and use whatever *Lore* becomes, plus *Notice* and maybe *Circles*.
- Due to the mystical element, *Lore* should be at least split into something like *Doxa*/Faith/Religion/Magic and *Episteme*/Knowledge. *Doxa* might be used for magic attacks as well as for the basic Lore trappings, given permission through Aspects or Stunts.
- The social skills need some adjusting. The split seems to generally run in the methods, and not in the results, so *Rapport* and *Provoke* are mingled into something like *Perform* (in front of an audience) and *Manipulate* (on a more symmetric level). *Manipulate* might eat up *Deceive*, as well. This reduces the number of social skills, which seems apt.
- The Greeks have three radically different ways of getting around: carts/chariots/…, horses and ships. This suggests renaming *Driving* into *Sail*, and if you don't want all the animal skills handled with *Athletics* and *Notice*, and *Animal Ken* skill might be appropriate. This is also possibly good to use instead of *Provoke* and *Rapport* to pacify Cerberus, get a Monster to come out of its lair etc.

This leaves the skill list as:
*Animal Ken*, *Athletics*, *Contacts*, *Crafts*, *Doxa*, *Empathy*, *Episteme*, *Fight*, *Manipulate*, *Notice*, *Perform*, *Physique*, *Resources*, *Sail*, *Shoot*, *Stealth* and *Will*.

Comment: Drop Burglary, its trappings go to Stealth. Drop Investigate. Ancient Greece was indeed a crime-free paradise where no one stole from anyone else or was curious about anything, was it not?

Comment: As you've noticed, taking cues from other games won't produce a skill list that's properly adapted to the needs of your group's campaign. Looking at other games is a decent place to start, to get your brain moving in the right direction, but it needs to just be inspiration rather than a template.

Comment: @Miniman: After some discussion in the character creation session, we went with Free-Form Professions. And a good part of the first session then consisted of the thug (not very sneakily) breaking into an appartment, and the party in general looking into gathering some juicy details on a politician they would like exiled. So much about my suggested skill list here not containing burglary and investigation, and how wrong this ansatz was…